Pdf Generation through IText7 Pdf .net
Demo File 1
"raw_header",
"value": "25 50 44 46 2D 31 2E 34 0A 25 E2 E3 CF D3 0A 35 20 30 20 6F 62 6A 0A 3C 3C 2F 46 69 6C 74 65 72 2F 46 6C 61 74 65 44 65 63 6F 64 65 2F 4C 65 6E 67 74 68 20 32 36 38 32 3E 3E 73 74 72 65 61 6D 0A 78 9C B5 9B DB 72 DB 38 12 86 EF F5 14 B8 D9 AA 4C 95 42 E2 4C D0 77 3A F8 A0 72 24 65 24 39 5B D9 4A 55 4A B1 15 47 3B 91 94 D8 4A 65 E7 ED 17 24 D1 04 98 B1 9A 22 39 93 B9 09 C6 F8 D0 C0"'
Demo File 2
"raw_header",
"value": "25 50 44 46 2D 31 2E 34 0A 25 E2 E3 CF D3 0A 35 20 30 20 6F 62 6A 0A 3C 3C 2F 46 69 6C 74 65 72 2F 46 6C 61 74 65 44 65 63 6F 64 65 2F 4C 65 6E 67 74 68 20 32 37 37 31 3E 3E 73 74 72 65 61 6D 0A 78 9C B5 9B DB 6E DB 3A 16 86 EF F3 14 BC 19 A0 1B 70 25 1E 75 C8 9D 0F 39 18 A9 ED 6C DB E9 A0 83 02 85 6A AB 89 A7 B1 DD DA CE CE F4 ED 87 92 B8 44 AA 13 2F 59 F2 9E F4 A6 4C F8 71 91 3F"'
#I need help when generating pdf from iText7 pdf .net application Raw_header value of each pdf file should be same

As far as the PDFs are concerned, your excerpts go far beyond the headers into the content. The only thing you can continuously expect is the PDF header "%PDF-", 25 50 44 46 2D. There is no reason to expect constant metadata beyond that.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I need help when generating pdf from iText7 pdf .net application Raw_header value of each pdf file should be same.

May I ask why you expect the 50 initial bytes of PDFs to coincide? It is not natural for PDFs to do so.
